# How can I suppress the Windows 10 1809 end of support notice?

Tags: powershell, windows-update, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

We have about 100 assets still running 1803 or 1809 and I would like to find a solution that can be pushed via command line or Powershell to stop users from seeing the notice.  The goal is to roll patching slowly over the next couple of weeks in batches, but we would like to avoid an influx of calls in the meantime while Microsoft starts notifying users their workstations are not safe or need to be updated.

Any scripts or tools that could help with this?  Is there a particular update that we can block to avoid the notice?  Any insight would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hopefully, you are targetting a version that will be supported, 1903 already will not receive security updates in December which less than 30 days away.

Comment: It seems cannot be achieved , please refer to: https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/23/microsoft-will-enforce-windows-10-upgrades-when-support-end-nears/

Comment: See this>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023814/some-versions-of-windows-10-display-a-notification-to-install-the-late